# OTP verification through SMS & Email while registration

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, registration

Are there any free plugins/extensions which send the OTP through registered email as well as a mobile number during the registration process?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally investigated or tested any of the following, but a quick Google search for `Joomla OTP verification` revealed:

- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/openotp-authentication/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/otp-verification-for-joomla/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/otp-verification-system-for-virtuemart/
- https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/loginguard.html

You should take it upon yourself to download and trial these extensions so that you can come to your own conclusion about which one is best suited to your application.  Please always do your due diligence before asking for help/support/advice.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info... but I have already tried all of these & back to stackexchange after that.. Anyway thanks for sharing..

Comment: Then please edit your question to show your research and effort.  Explain why/how these existing free extensions are not suitable for your application.  This will make your question more valuable and hopefully progress your question to a resolution.